Show that $ S_n - \sigma_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^n ja_j \leq M$
in the book "Real Analysis via Sequences and Series" there is an exercise that I don't know how to solve it.
Suppose that $\vert na_n\vert \leq M \ for \ all \ n \geq 0$. Show that
$$ S_n - \sigma_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^n ja_j \leq M$$
for all n, where $Sn = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \ and \ \sigma _n =\sum_{j=0}^n S_j$ for all n.
My approach:
$$S_n - \sigma _n = Sn - \sum_{j=0}^n S_j = - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}S_j$$
As we have that:
$S_0 = a_0$
$S_1 = a_0 + a_1$
$S_2 = a_0+a_1+a_2$
$S_3 = a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3$
$......................$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}S_j = na_0 + (n-1)a_1 + (n-2)a_2  \dots = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(n-j)a_j $$
Then:
$$S_n - \sigma _n = -\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}Sj = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j-n)a_j = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}ja_j - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}na_j$$
I don't know how to continue $\dots$
Thank you so much

Did you try induction?

by definition $\sigma_n = \sum_{j=0}^n S_j$ not $ \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^n S_j$

Your calculation is sound. It seems that the problem is not stated correctly, probably a typo. A counterexample is, for example, if we take $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}, n\geq 0$. We take an upper bound $M=1$ and observe that the condition
\begin{align*}
|na_n|=\frac{n}{n+1}<1\qquad n\geq 0
\end{align*}
is fulfilled. With $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}, n\geq 0$ we see that
\begin{align*}
S_n=\sum_{j=0}^na_j=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{j+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{j}=H_{n+1}>0
\end{align*}
is the $(n+1)$-th harmonic number which is positive for all $n\geq 0$.
Let's consider the first part of the claim:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S_n-\sigma_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n}ja_j} \qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We take $n\geq 1$ and see that the left-hand side of (1) is negative:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S_n-\sigma_n}&=S_n-\sum_{j=0}^nS_j=-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}S_j=-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}H_{j+1}\\
&=-\sum_{j=1}^{n}H_{j}\color{blue}{<0}
\end{align*}
But the right-hand side of (1) is positive:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{n}ja_j}=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{j}{j+1}\color{blue}{>0}
\end{align*}
which indicates a typo in the stated problem.
